# Stanford NER - Unable to identify Phone number

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am training my NER to the entity type Phonenumber whose part of speech is number. However when I test the same data that I have trained, the phone number is not identified by the classifier. [image]

Is that because the part of speech(POS) of phone number is number(CD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `regexner` instead for this use case.

Consider this sentence (put it in phone-number-example.txt):

`You can reach the office at 555 555-5555.`

If you make a `regexner` rules file like this (note each column is tab separated)

```
[0-9]{3}\W[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}     PHONE_NUMBER    MISC,NUMBER     1
```

And run this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -regexner.mapping phone_number.rules -file phone-number-example.txt -outputFormat text
```

It will identify the phone number in the output NER tagging.

One issue to look out for.  You will note the tokenizer turns "555 555-5555" into one token.  The first column of the rule file is a regex that matches a token.  The regexner patterns are a space separated list of patterns that match each token you want to ner tag.

So in this example, the rule I made has a "\W" to capture the space.  The rule wasn't working when I used "\s", etc..so I think there is an issue with writing regexes for tokens that contain spaces.  Typically tokens don't contain spaces for that matter.

So you might want to work around this by expanding on "\W" and excluding other characters that you don't want since "\W" just means non-word characters.  Also, you can obviously make the pattern I just listed more complicated and capture the various phone number patterns.

More info on RegexNER can be found here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html